# Pegar dados de Video pelo ID - YouTube Data API (v3) - em PHP

Tags: php, youtube

Eu tenho um formulário, que cadastra videos do youtube usando apenas o ID.
Terei uma página para reproduzir esse vídeo.

Alem de reproduzir o vídeo ( isso já conseguir fazer ) eu preciso de algo ( API ) para trazer mais informações dele, Como:  Titulo, e duração.

Alguem que ja fez isso em PHP pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Ja dei uma olhada na DOC, porem tenho pouco XP, com as habilidades que tenho não conseguir fazer funcionar.

Comment: Possivel duplicata de [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63208/3635](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63208/3635)? - PS: resposta **sobre PHP**: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/297239/3635

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Youtube API V3 Informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63208/youtube-api-v3-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es)